# Radio group with shinyalert in R

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to paste radio group in shinyalert modal window and access selected result after it is closed (OK pressed). As package author @DeanAttali says, any HTML input can be used.

My problems:

1) I don't understand how to add inputId to radio group,

2) label for each radio is rendered below (not inline, see code sample),

3) input field (text input) is rendered after radios but I don't want it to be used.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyalert)
shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage( 
    useShinyalert(),
    actionButton("btn", "Click me") ), 

  server = function(input, output) { 
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      # Show a simple modal 
      shinyalert(title = "You did it!", type = "input",inputType = "radio",text=
                   "<style type=\"text/css\">
                .block1 { 
                 padding: 5px;
                 display: inline;
                 vertical-align:middle;
                 } </style> <div class=\"block1\"><input type=\"radio\" id=\"contactChoice1\"
                 name=\"contact\" value=\"email\">
                   <label for=\"contactChoice1\">Email</label></div>
                   <div class=\"block1\"><input type=\"radio\" id=\"contactChoice2\"
                 name=\"contact\" value=\"phone\">
                   <label for=\"contactChoice2\">Phone</label></div>",
                 animation="slide-from-top",html = TRUE)
    })

    # observe({
    #   if(is.null(input$myalert)) // I don't understand where to set ID
    #   {return()}
    #   print(input$myalert)
    # 
    # })
})
```

Comment: Did you try https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html?

Comment: @A. Suliman, thank you for advice but I'd like to clarify case with shinyalert

Comment: You can use `shiny::radioButtons` instead of writing your own radio buttons.